# How to remove the <br> and space from the JSON output in powershell

Tags: json, xml, powershell

Need your help on this. When I am fetching the description from the json file. I am getting a gibberish string output. Need to remove the HTML tags and space but i couldnt find anything thats fits my question.

Lastly, After we remove the tags and spacces.. how do i get the output of specific field. like Last Name value and Department. Thanks!

Correct output should be something like this,

```
Last Name: Tes Last name <br/>
Preferred Name: Test name <br/>
Company: test Company<br/>
Department: Test Department<br/>
```

Code I am currently using:

```
$request = 'https://****F'
Invoke-WebRequest $request |
ConvertFrom-Json  |
select -expand request |
Select -expand description  ;# -replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi '')
```

[image: **output with issue**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is HTML (or at least a HTML fragment), so the best approach would be to use an HTML parser.

Given that these aren't readily available, you can **try the following string-parsing approach**:

```
$requestDescr = 
  Invoke-WebRequest 'https://****F' |
   ConvertFrom-Json  |
    Select -expand request |
     Select -expand description 

$cleanLines = ($requestDescr -split '<br */>|</?div>').Trim() -ne ''
```

- `$requestDescr -split '<br */>|</?div>'` splits the input by `<br>` and `<div>` elements (using a regular expression)
- `.Trim()` removes leading and trailing whitespaces from all resulting strings.
- `-ne ''` then filters out empty strings.

This should yield an array of lines such as:

```
Please set up an Active Directory account for Lou Segouci
Job Req ID: 417
Middle Name:
Last Name: Segoucy
Title: Payment Processing Keyer
```

---

In order to **convert that to a hashtable**:

```
$fieldsTable = [ordered] @{}
$cleanLines -match ':' | 
  foreach { $key, $value = $_ -split ': *', 2; $fieldsTable[$key] = $value }
```

- `$key, $value = $_ -split ': *', 2` splits each line into 2 tokens by `:` optionally followed by whitespace, and stores the tokens in distinct variables.
- `$fieldsTable[$key] = $value` then adds an entry for this key-value pair.

Note: To facilitate later access by property (key) name, you could use 
`$fieldsTable[$key -replace ' '] = $value` to simplify key names, so that entry `Job Req ID` can more simply be accessed as `JobReqId`.

`$fieldsTable` is now an (ordered) hashtable with key names `Job Req ID`, `Middle Name`, ..., allowing you to extract properties with expressions such as `$fieldsTable['Job Req ID']`.

```
# Contents of $fieldsTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Job Req ID                     417
Middle Name                   
Last Name                      Segouci
Title                          Payment Processing Keyer
```